# (Kotlin) Any workaround for annotation processing in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, annotations, code-generation

I've created a gradle modules `main` that contains main program logic and `codegen` that contains annotation definitions with processors. I found that:

> > Please note that kapt is still not supported for IntelliJ IDEA’s own build system. Launch the build from the “Maven Projects” toolbar whenever you want to re-run the annotation processing.

on kapt page (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html) but I really need it. May be there is some (may be ugly) workaround for that? Terminal background worker or prebuild tasks or something else?

*P.S.*
*This can appear as duplicate question but I really didn't found working solution at the moment*

Answer (score 1):

At the current project we have this problem as well; we use gradle and the work around is to run `gradle classes testClasses` from the commandline - either in an external terminal program or in IJ's terminal (alt-F12 on macOS). This triggers *kapt* as well, and when this is done I do a *Build/Rebuild project* from IJ's menu as well.

This is enough if the code that is processed by *kapt* does not change too often (we just use mapstruct and querydsl).

If you are using maven a `mvn compile test-compile` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that repository that does work in Intellij IDEA without any workarounds (https://github.com/miquelbeltran/kotlin-code-gen-sample). Taken from https://medium.com/@Miqubel/hello-world-of-annotation-processing-in-kotlin-3ec0290c1fdd